# Chrome (Webkit) not showing PDFs with non-ASCII characters in filenames, any workaround?

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, webkit, opera

You can see this résumé in PDF http://www.gelbukh.com/r%E9sum%E9.pdf (with accented characters in the filename) in FireFox and in IE, but not in Chrome or Opera.

The problem is specific to PDF: you can see a TXT http://www.gelbukh.com/r%E9sum%E9.txt in Chrome and Opera.

Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround other than to restrict filenames on the server to ASCII?